# Globally inline CSS imported by JS or TS files?

Tags: css, vite

Vite's default is to extract the CSS into `styles.css`.
This happens even if I use ES imports.
There is a way to inline by adding `?inline` to every import I want to inline.
When I try to use that, I get the following error:

> `error TS2307: Cannot find module './data-grid-row.scss?inline' or its corresponding type declarations.`

In addition, this is hacky because I have more than 60 inline CSS imports and I don't want to add `?inline` to all of them.

Is there a way to set the inline styles ES imports as the default without adding all the `?inline` suffixes?